Velocity-Continuity in Layered Poiseuille Flow
Consider a flow situation in which a channel is filled with two immiscible fluids, one of density $\rho_1$ and viscosity $\mu_1$, the other of density $\rho_2$ and viscosity $\mu_2$. In an undergraduate lecture, the instructor wrote out the boundary conditions that the flow field must satisfy at the interface-
$$ \mu_1 \frac{du_1}{dy} = \mu_2 \frac{du_2}{dy} \tag{1}$$
and
$$ u_1 = u_2. \tag{2}$$
Now, (1) can easily be rationalized by appealing to Newton's third law. The second, however, is a bit harder for me to wrap my head around. I know this is simply a case of not having sufficiently well-developed physical intuition, but it seems plausible - at least in principle - that the velocity could be discontinuous at the interface.
Why do we have to impose (2)?

Probably because at the interface of fluids both viscosities must match, this can be only when both derivatives cancel each other out, in case $u_1=u_2=u.$

@AgniusVasiliauskas We're assuming that the fluids are immiscible - how could the viscosities match at the interface?

Just substitute $u$ into (1) and you'll get $\mu_1 = \mu_2$. So either there's an error in the boundary condition (1) OR an error in false assumption that at the interface fluids are immiscible / uninteracting.

Third option is that condition $u_1 = u_2$ is invalid for immiscible fluids.

@AgniusVasiliauskas This already assumes that $u_1 = u_2$ - which is what I want justified. Secondly, even if $u_1 = u_2$ at the boundary, this doesn't imply that the derivatives are equal. ie (2) doesn't imply (1).

I never said, that (2) implies (1), just that according to (2) at the boundary, $$\mu_1 \frac{du}{dy} = \mu_2 \frac{du}{dy},$$ so $$\mu_1 = \mu_2.$$ And so (2) shows that fluids must interact at the boundary. And this is justification, not an assumption.

What you are talking about is the so called no-slip boundary condition for viscous fluids .  /tgus gas beeb fibbed ti be correct observationallyy.

You are right in assuming (1) comes from continous shear stress.
For immiscible fluid interfaces, one generally enforces what is called a kinematic boundary condition. Letting $\eta$ denote the interface between the two fluids, then:
$$ \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial t} + \mathbf{u}_i \cdot \nabla \eta = 0$$
is an appropriate boundary condition. This condition states that a particle on the boundary remains on the boundary (in an idealised sense), which enforces immiscibility.
If, however, $\eta$ is a constant, then it follows that this boundary condition is automatically fulfilled as all its derivatives are zero. Hence, both fluids effectively become solid boundaries to each other, and a typical no-slip condition becomes appropriate, or in other words, $u_1 = u_2$ at the boundary.
